# How safe is it to use Selenium to auto-fill forms with sensitive information

Tags: selenium, security, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, user-agent

Selenium is usually used for testing. But what if someone decided to use it to autofill forms on websites with personal data(username, password, credit card number). How safe would that be?

I mean the actual part where you call the driver object and pass it all this secure information. Let's assume the information is securely stored until the moment you pass it to the driver.

I wonder if that's what websites that aggregate your credit card and bank accounts use instead of api calls(running a headless browser in the backend to log in to personal profiles).

Comment: I think what you mean is how safe is it for the browser to store sensitive information...  it's convenience vs. security.  If someone gains access to your machine/login, they could obviously use that information to make purchases.

Answer (score 2):

While using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) as mentioned in the [Security](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#security) section within [WebDriver - W3C Recommendation](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/) the only security concern is that:

> A user agent that rely on a command-line flag or a configuration option to test whether to enable [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491), or alternatively make the user agent initiate or confirm the connection through a privileged content document or control widget, in case the user agent does not directly implement the HTTP endpoints.
>
> It is strongly suggested that user agents require users to take explicit action to enable WebDriver, and that WebDriver remains disabled in publicly consumed versions of the user agent.
>
> To prevent arbitrary machines on the network from connecting and creating sessions, it is suggested that only connections from loopback devices are allowed by default.
>
> The remote end can include a configuration option to limit the accepted IP range allowed to connect and make requests. The default setting for this might be to limit connections to the IPv4 localhost CIDR range **`127.0.0.0/8`** and the IPv6 localhost address **`::1`**.

The generic solution was to distinguish the user agent session that is under control of *WebDriver* from those used for normal browsing sessions. Snapshot of visually distinguishable WebDriver driven user agent:

[image: WebDriver_driven_UserAgent]

Comment: so in our selenium code we must include a line saying it can only run on the local host? I dont know if this is a good question but if someone received that code and put it on their computer wouldnt it also be running on a local host and still be able to run?